# Images Randomly Disappearing in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, image, delete-file

I have been having a strange issue happen that started suddenly. My images in my posts are randomly disappearing. I have changed themes, turned off plugins and checked the error logs. I called my hosting company and they can't figure it out either. I've been debugging this issue for almost two weeks now. They disappear from the media library, and the server. It's like the images were never uploaded at all. I even did a fresh install on another site to see if it still happened, and it is happening on that site too. But most of the plugins are different. This is very frustrating!
Here's a list of the plugins I have:
ACF Pro
ACF Frontend Forms
Advanced Database Cleaner PRO: Not active for debugging
Advanced Editor Tools (previously TinyMCE Advanced)
Advanced Post Queries
BuddyPress
Classic Widgets
Code Snippets: no snippets added that affect the media library
Elementor
Elementor Pro
Enlighter - Customizable Syntax Highlighter
Happy Elementor Addons
JetEngine
JetSmart Filters
JetTabs
User Role Editor
WP Mail SMTP
wpDiscuz
Youzify

THEME: Kava was the original, but I changed to Customify to further debug, so that's what's active right now.

Does anyone know how to trace what is calling for the deletion of these images? Or at least have a clue as to what could be causing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out! It was a cron job setting in wpDiscuz plugin! It was set to delete any images not attached to a post. Once I deleted the cron job, the issue stopped. I NEVER would have guessed that a comment plugin would do that! It took a long time to figure it out. But at least I know what it is now.